# How to override component styles from scss?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a component library that uses the following standard to create components:

```
// component.scss
.component {
  margin: 0;
}


// Component.jsx
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classNames';

import './component.scss';

const Component = React.forwardRef(({ className, ...rest }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={classNames('component', className)}>
  )
});
```

The problem is the scss classes have higher specificity than the passed in classNames.
So if the scss specifies a margin, a class passed in with a margin attribute gets overwritten.

How can I prevent this from happening without having to resort to using `!important` in className? Is there a better way to structure the component?

Comment: Questions. (1) Is this a component library you have built yourself or is it one that is off the shelf? (2) Where is the CSS for the passed in class names written? Is that in some other scss file? Or the same one? Or unknown.

Comment: (3) Provide example selector in the scss file which has a high specificity.

Comment: I have built this component library myself

Comment: In that case, you usually want to make the CSS such that it does not rely on high-specificity rules. There's quite a few conventions for achieving this, but the most popular is BEM (block, element, modifier). Research this. Since you only ever have flat class names with this naming convention, the problem goes away. https://getbem.com/

Comment: See here https://getbem.com/faq/#:~:text=Another%20point%20is%20CSS%20specificity specifically for how this strategy helps.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The scss is still preferred by the browser

Comment: It won't be, because the specificity of the scss contents will be lower, meaning passed in classes will not be overridden. Read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. Scss is not somehow automatically preferred by the browser...its the way the selectors are modelled (high specificity) which is causing you issues. As above, the faq on bem describes exactly the scenario. It should also be ensured that the passed in class names are later in the compiled source order.

Comment: It could be a problem with the order of your style imports. Have you tried to increase specificity of the _custom_ selector? like this `.custom-class.custom-class`